# MercadoPago Connect y one click to pay

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy intentando hacer una mezcla de mercadopago connect y one click to pay.

Desde mi aplicación estoy cobrando en nombre de varios clientes y obteniendo una comisión por ello.

Mi idea es que cuando un usuario pague por primera vez, guardar esa tarjeta para posteriormente usarla para hacer pagos con un solo clic.

El problema es que el pago con un solo clic (one clic to pay) cuando quiero usar la tarjeta guardado solo me deja hacerlo para transacciones del mismo cliente con la que hice la primera.

Por ejemplo:
- cta_comision
- cta_cte_1
- cta_cte_2
- usuario_1

Hago un cobro (cargando todos los datos de la tarjeta) de "cta_cte_1" al "usuario_1". Posteriormente guardo el cliente y la tarjeta.
Posteriormente quiero usar esa tarjeta guardada para hacer un cobro de "cta_cte_2" y me da error.

**¿ Como podría guardar las tarjetas de un cliente de manera que pueda ser usada en todas las aplicaciones que tengo ?**

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar las tarjetas asociadas a un cliente usando el token generado con mercadopago connect pero este token es construido con el ID de aplicación por lo que las tarjetas solo podrán ser consultadas desde la aplicación de origen.

Podrias tener una aplicación única con varias instancias de front-end lo que te permitiria guardar las tarjetas en la aplicación principal y usarlas en los portales secundarios de igual manera usando mp connect.

Comment: Gracias Joel por la respuesta.
Te cuento que logro generar el card_token inicial (con todos los datos de la tarjeta) con el public key de la app y usarlo para en cualquiera de las cuentas (por medio del access_token) desde las que quiero cobrar, que previamente autorizaron a la app a hacerlo.

Después guardo esa tarjeta en un customer asociado a la app. 

Cuando genero nuevamente un card_token, de nuevo con el public_key de la app pero esta vez solicitando solo el CSV de la tarjeta almacenada y quiero usar ese token para cobrar con una cuenta me devuelve error "2002: Customer not found".

Comment: Hola @martinodetti, probablemente es medio tarde pero tal vez la respuesta que di en esta [consulta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50287/5926) te sirva