# ¿Por qué recibo el error "Customer Not Found" al intentar pagos con tarjetas guardadas?

Tags: android, nodejs, mercadopago

Estoy probando los pagos con una tarjeta guardada. Cada vez que intento generar el pago en mi servidor (node.js) recibo el error de MercadoPago 2002: Customer not found. El error solamente ocurre cuando ocupo la tarjeta como guardada, sin embargo si uso la misma tarjeta ingresandola manualmente, esto no ocurre.

Estos son los datos que envió para el crear el pago:

```
var payment = {
binary_mode : true,
description : req.body.eventInfo.title,
transaction_amount : req.body.paymentInfo.total,
payment_method_id : req.body.paymentInfo.paymentMethod,
issuer_id : req.body.paymentInfo.issuer,
token : req.body.paymentInfo.token,
installments : req.body.paymentInfo.installments,
payer : {
  email : req.body.userInfo.email
}
```

El front-end que utilizo es Android y no genera ningún error.
La tarjeta de prueba que estoy usando son las proporcionadas por MercadoPago.

Ya me he paseado por toda la documentación de MercadoPago y no he encontrado nada útil.

---

**EDIT**: Continué con mis pruebas y entendí que debo agregar el ID del *Customer* en la solicitud para crear el pago. Ahora la cuestión es que el `customer_id` es un String (Ej. `"244287696-igVP5aqibPydEp"`) y la solicitud requiere que en el campo `payer.id` se coloque un Integer. Ya intente usando los primeros números del ID (Ej. `244287696`) pero me devuelve el mismo error "Customer not found".

Hice el mismo procedimiento con la tarjeta guardada, y con una introducida manualmente, ambos el mismo resultado. Realmente la documentación es muy pobre y no encuentro solución aún.

---

**EDIT 2**: Finalmente encontré la razón del problema y una solución. Gracias a @hdlopez por su respuesta, continué probando enviar el customer_id como String y obviamente me devolvió el siguiente error:

```
Error: The next fields are failing n validation: ".payer.id": should be integer.
     at Object.requestManager.buildRequest (/app/node_modules/mercadopago/lib/request-manager.js:270:17)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mercadopago/lib/request-manager.js:302:18)
     at Promise._execute (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
     at new Promise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
     at Object.requestManager.exec (/app/node_modules/mercadopago/lib/request-manager.js:296:10)
     at /app/node_modules/mercadopago/lib/request-manager.js:106:31
     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:10)
     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
     at runCallback (timers.js:649:20)
     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:622:5)
```

De lo que no me había percatado es que es un error del SDK de MercadoPago, no un error devuelto por su API. Entonces probé hacer el request de manera manual con cliente REST. Lo hice con los siguientes datos de prueba:

```
{
    "transaction_amount": 100,
    "token": "274ea...",
    "description": "Title of what you are paying for",
    "payment_method_id" : "master",
    "installments": 1,
    "payer": {
        "id": "244287696-igVP5aqibPydEp"
    }
}
```

Y me devolvió el pago correctamente sin ningún error. Como solución temporal estoy usando un cliente HTTP REST en mi servidor para enviar la solicitud de pago.

El error ocurre con el SDK de MercadoPago "px-nodejs-1.0.0" y voy a ver como puedo reportar este bug.

Comment: Sería bueno que muestres como guardas las tarjetas y como las implementas.

Comment: @x4mp73r Ahí agregue parte de mi código pero al parecer el problema pasa por el ID del _Customer_ (como aclaro en el _edit_) ¿Que te parece?

Comment: @GuidoTaján El problema esta solucionado. La SDK de Node.JS realiza una verificación del JSON antes de ser enviado. Es por esto que el problema se da en la SDK y no en la API. Ya esta solucionado!, por favor borrar el paquete de node_modules (si estas referenciando al repositorio) e instalalo nuevamente!. Si encontras otro problema no dudes en abrir un issue como hiciste para este caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a ver si te puedo ayudar. Vamos punto por punto:

**Alta de tarjeta (creación de customer)**

Una vez creado el *customer* como dice la [documentación](https://github.com/mercadopago/code-examples/blob/master/customized-checkout/customers/java/create_customer.java#L8) puedes asociarle una tarjeta a partir de un token de tarjeta (*card token*). En este punto, asegurate que el cuando crees el token de tarjeta hayas ingresado el nombre del dueño de la tarjeta (card holder name). Hay veces que esto puede dar problemas, no necesariamente, pero es una buena práctica.

**Pago con tarjeta guardada**

Una vez [creada la tarjeta](https://github.com/mercadopago/code-examples/blob/master/customized-checkout/customers/java/add_card.java#L14) para cierto customer obtienes información de dicha tarjeta guardada, entre ellos el *id*. Con ese id tendrás que crear un *card token*. Este token es el que enviarás en el pago.

Respecto al *payer.id* que debes enviar en el pago, no he encontrado donde dice que este campo es integer. Intenta enviar en dicho campo el customer_id que has mencionado, ej: `"244287696-igVP5aqibPydEp"`

```
var payment = {
  binary_mode : true,
  description : req.body.eventInfo.title,
  transaction_amount : req.body.paymentInfo.total,
  payment_method_id : req.body.paymentInfo.paymentMethod,
  issuer_id : req.body.paymentInfo.issuer,
  token : req.body.paymentInfo.token,
  installments : req.body.paymentInfo.installments,
  payer : {
    id: "244287696-igVP5aqibPydEp"// Customer ID del payer
    email : req.body.userInfo.email
  }
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias @hdlopez Encontré que el error se produce por el SDK de MercadoPago para node.js. Voy a usar un cliente REST para crear los pagos correctamente.